# Анимация тени блока / текста по круговой траектории?

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation

Я пытаюсь использовать CSS-анимацию для создания эффекта источника света, указывающего на объект вниз, отбрасывающего тень. И кругового движения вокруг него. Я создал фрагмент ниже, чтобы показать, что у меня получилось.

Решение вроде бы близко, но на данный момент (потому что у меня всего 4 ключевых кадра) получается, что источник света движется по квадратной траектории. Я бы хотел, чтобы он выглядел так, как будто он движется по круговой траектории.

Единственное решение, которое я могу придумать, чтобы приблизиться к круговой траектории, - это добавить еще несколько ключевых кадров и создать (для простоты) путь в форме двенадцатиугольника, но есть ли более простое решение?
Есть ли какая-то функция времени, которую я мог бы использовать, чтобы упростить ее?
Или я могу использовать какую-то функцию Sass для автоматического вычисления промежуточных ключевых кадров?

Я должен был заметить, что как только я получу эту работу с тенями блока, я также хотел бы применить тот же метод к теням текста.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
  box-shadow: 50px 50px 5px darkgrey;
  animation: orbit-shadow 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes orbit-shadow {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 50px 50px 5px darkgrey;
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: -50px 50px 5px darkgrey;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: -50px -50px 5px darkgrey;
  }
  75% {
    box-shadow: 50px -50px 5px darkgrey;
  }
  1000% {
    box-shadow: 50px 50px 5px darkgrey;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Animating a box-shadow/text-shadow on a circular path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63502603/7394871) от участника  [@itsViney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14136436/itsviney).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63502603/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Для этого нужно учитывать ротацию. Используйте псевдоэлемент, чтобы не вращать основной элемент:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin:50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
  position:relative;
}
.circle::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius:inherit;
  box-shadow: 50px 50px 5px darkgrey;
  animation: orbit-shadow 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes orbit-shadow {
  100% {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}

body{
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Или вы просто поворачиваете элемент, если у вас не будет содержимого:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
  box-shadow: 50px 50px 5px darkgrey;
  animation: orbit-shadow 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes orbit-shadow {
  100% {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}

body{
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Другая идея

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin:50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
  position:relative;
}
.circle::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius:inherit;
  background:darkgrey;
  filter:blur(5px);
  animation: orbit-shadow 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes orbit-shadow {
  0% {
    transform:rotate(0deg)   translate(50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotate(360deg) translate(50px);
  }
}

body{
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Вы также можете сделать то же самое для `text-shadow` с немного другой анимацией, чтобы текст не поворачивался:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.circle {
  position:relative;
  font-size:40px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.circle::before,
.circle::after{
  content:attr(data-text);
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}

.circle::before {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  color:transparent;
  text-shadow:0 0 5px darkgrey;
  animation: orbit-shadow 5s linear infinite;
}
/* the 50px is your offset */
@keyframes orbit-shadow {
  0% {
    transform:rotate(0deg)   translate(50px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotate(360deg) translate(50px) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
body{
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle" data-text="some text"></div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63502700/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>